# How do you change the wpallimport capabilities

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

The default capability is 'manage_options'. How do you customize the capability so I can add this to any user role I want?

Comment: As a standalone question, this doesn't contain enough details to be viable - IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can edit the static property of PMXI_Plugin on init

```php
add_action('init', function () {
    PMXI_Plugin::$capabilities = 'wpallimport_manage';
});
```